# SSL_CERT_DIR not avaluated by urrlib2

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, ssl-certificate, urllib2

I have a small script to test connections to a self-signed `https` site using `urllib2:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

try:
    import urllib2  # python2
except:
    import urllib.request as urllib2  # python3
import sys

req = urllib2.Request(sys.argv[1], headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

I am testing my self-signed https site, like this:

```
SSL_CERT_FILE="/certs-dir/self-signed-site.crt" python urllib2_test.py https://localhost:5554
```

And this works.

But this does not:

```
SSL_CERT_DIR="/certs-dir" python urllib2_test.py https://localhost:5554
```

Neither does this work:

```
SSL_CERT_DIR="/certs-dir/self-signed-site.crt" python urllib2_test.py https://localhost:5554
```

There is a [discussion](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/2899) on adding support for this to `requests`, but I do not find references to `SSL_CERT_DIR` in `urllib2`. There must be something, maybe through the underlying `ssl` library?

Where is the handling of `SSL_CERT_FILE` / `SSL_CERT_DIR` defined for `urrlib2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SSL_CERT_DIR and SSL_CERT_FILE are not features of urllib2 or requests but of the underlying OpenSSL library. But, it is not enough to just throw a new certificate into the given directory, you need to use a proper filename with the hash of the certificate. See [rehash](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/rehash.html) for more information.

Comment: Still it seems support is needed for the corresponding python library (see the requests discussion).

Comment: But you are right, running `c_rehash .` in the certificates directory allows me to use `SSL_CERT_DIR`. Thanks!